# NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy in design-time mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress, security-policy

Is there any way to make legacy design-time code execute with NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy switched on?

More specificaly, is there any way to make DevExpress 8.2 winforms designer work in VisualStudio 2010?

I got errors due to this issue and found no help about design-time mode, just about run-time:

```
<runtime>
  <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

How should I fix problems with winforms designer?

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding the corresponding attribute to devenv.exe config file, just like to my own application configuration.

Comment: I fixed the problem in ASP.net devEnv adding the atribbute to thee Cassine config in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe.config`

Answer (score 22):

Just add this

```
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
```

into your **VS2010 DevEnv configuration file**, you'll find it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`

There is a `<runtime>` section, just copy it at the first place.
I've had the same problem with DevExpress 8.2

If some people face the same problem while developing **ASP.Net apps**, they should add the Attribute to the Cassini config file placed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe.config`

Comment: I'm having the same issue and adding the setting to devenv.exe.config fixed the designer issue, but now I'm getting errors compiling: "The security state of an AppDomain was modified by an AppDomainManager configured with the NoSecurityChanges flag." from my WPF code... Any ideas?

Comment: And from projects that have COM references.