# AppDomainManager error trying to install Ajax Control Toolkit in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to add the Ajax Control Toolkit v.NET35 to my toolbox in VS 2010.  After I navigate to the AjaxControlToolkit.dll, I get a popup that reads "The security state of an AppDomain was modified by an AppDomainManager configured with the NoSecurityChanges flag."

I am running VS2010 as an administrator, and I have added the lines;

```
<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
<legacyCasPolicy enabled="true" />
```

to both my devenv.exe.config and web.config files, but to no avail.

I've searched and found quite a few people with this problem, but no resolution that works 100%.

Anyone else solved this one?

TIA
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try to login to DX account and upgrade your hotfix of the version 2008.3. This are fixed for people: [Legacy Security Policy in Visual Studio 2010 and COM References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697421/legacy-security-policy-in-visual-studio-2010-and-com-references)

Comment: Is this caused by DevExpress 8.3?  I didn't mention DX at all.  I *do* have both DX 8.3 and 10.1 DLLs installed on my machine.  Until recently, I had the 10.1 tools in my VS 2010 toolbox but they've disapppeared.  But at any rate, I did download and re-install DX 8.3.8 and I'm still getting the same error.