# Visual Studio 2013 crashes with NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy - Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain?

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2013

Using the [<NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy> Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409253(v=vs.110).aspx) enables me to use .NET 2.0 controls under the old .NET 2.0 licensing in the Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 Windows Forms designers, as required to develop for the [TRAVERSE](http://www.osas.com/traverse) ecosystem. (See [NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy in design-time mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637089/netfx40-legacysecuritypolicy-in-design-time-mode).)

However, that same setting forces Visual Studio 2013 to crash immediately open showing.
Is there a workaround, or am I forced to install Visual Studio 2012 to use the Forms designer?

It calls Environment.FailFast with the message "Failed to schedule time on the UI thread. A continuation would never execute." and the exception it caught, which is an InvalidOperationException with the message "Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain."

The call stack at the original exception:

```
System.Core.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore<System.Func<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler>>(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite<System.Func<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite,object,System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler>> site, object[] args) Line 41 + 0x33 bytes    C#
System.Core.dll!System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1<object,System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler>(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, object arg0) Line 277 + 0x31 bytes C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.SchedulerModifyingJoinableTaskFactoryWrapper.PostToUnderlyingSynchronizationContext(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback callback, object state) Line 401 + 0x7d bytes    C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.PostToUnderlyingSynchronizationContextOrThreadPool(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.SingleExecuteProtector callback) Line 98 + 0x1e bytes C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.Post(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback d, object state, bool mainThreadAffinitized) Line 314   C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.RequestSwitchToMainThread(System.Action callback) Line 134    C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.MainThreadAwaiter.OnCompleted(System.Action continuation) Line 362 + 0xb bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.AwaitOnCompleted<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.MainThreadAwaiter,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.<int>.<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.MainThreadAwaiter awaiter, ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.<int>.<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c stateMachine) Line 47 + 0x9 bytes C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync<int>() Line 159 + 0xc0 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.<int>.<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.<int>.<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c stateMachine) Line 30 + 0x8 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.<int>.<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.<int>.<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c stateMachine) Line 27 + 0xd bytes   C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync<int>.AnonymousMethod__1c() + 0x77 bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync<int>(System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>> asyncMethod, bool synchronouslyBlocking) Line 191 + 0xa bytes C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.RunAsync<int>(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory joinableTaskFactory, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskRunContext priority, System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>> asyncMethod) Line 328 + 0x24 bytes C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync<int>(System.Func<int> func) Line 158 + 0x40 bytes   C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync<int>>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync<int> stateMachine) Line 30 + 0x8 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync<int>>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync<int> stateMachine) Line 27 + 0xd bytes   C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync<int>(System.Func<int> func) + 0x77 bytes    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkThroughVsWebProxy(System.Uri url, bool okToPrompt, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Logger logger) Line 206 + 0x1ec bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkThroughVsWebProxy>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkThroughVsWebProxy stateMachine) Line 30 + 0x8 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkThroughVsWebProxy>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkThroughVsWebProxy stateMachine) Line 27 + 0xd bytes    C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkThroughVsWebProxy(System.Uri url, bool okToPrompt, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Logger logger) + 0x96 bytes  
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkAsync(System.Uri url, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Logger logger, int retryCount) Line 170 + 0x1c bytes  C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkAsync>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkAsync stateMachine) Line 30 + 0x8 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkAsync>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkAsync stateMachine) Line 27 + 0xd bytes    C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkAsync(System.Uri url, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Logger logger, int retryCount) + 0x96 bytes   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserContext.PrepareToConnectAndComputeCodeMarker() Line 153 + 0x11e bytes   C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserContext.PrepareToConnectAndComputeCodeMarker>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserContext.PrepareToConnectAndComputeCodeMarker stateMachine) Line 30 + 0x8 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserContext.PrepareToConnectAndComputeCodeMarker>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserContext.PrepareToConnectAndComputeCodeMarker stateMachine) Line 27 + 0xd bytes    C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserContext.PrepareToConnectAndComputeCodeMarker() + 0x81 bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsyncImpl(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 168 + 0x13 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsyncImpl>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsyncImpl stateMachine) Line 30 + 0x8 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsyncImpl>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsyncImpl stateMachine) Line 27 + 0xd bytes    C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsyncImpl(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) + 0x8c bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Line 132 + 0x35 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsync>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsync stateMachine) Line 30 + 0x8 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsync>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsync stateMachine) Line 27 + 0xd bytes    C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) + 0x8c bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.PollConnectAsync() Line 412 + 0x26 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.PollConnectAsync>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.PollConnectAsync stateMachine) Line 30 + 0x8 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<int>.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.PollConnectAsync>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.PollConnectAsync stateMachine) Line 27 + 0xd bytes   C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.PollConnectAsync() + 0x77 bytes 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Poller.PollAsync() Line 118 + 0x10 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Poller.PollAsync>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Poller.PollAsync stateMachine) Line 30 + 0x8 bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Poller.PollAsync>(ref Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Poller.PollAsync stateMachine) Line 26 + 0xd bytes    C#
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Poller.PollAsync(object unused) + 0x80 bytes    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(object state) Line 67 + 0xe bytes   C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 288 + 0xd bytes  C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Line 260 + 0xd bytes  C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback() Line 58 + 0xc bytes    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire() Line 172   C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers() Line 166 + 0x8 bytes  C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback() Line 30 + 0x1c bytes  C#
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

In the event log when it crashes:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: Failed to schedule time on the UI thread. A continuation would never execute.
Stack:
at System.Environment.FailFast(System.String, System.Exception)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory+MainThreadAwaiter.OnCompleted(System.Action)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].AwaitOnCompleted[[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory+MainThreadAwaiter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a],[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities+<>c__DisplayClass1d`1+<<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c>d__1f[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](MainThreadAwaiter ByRef, <<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c>d__1f<Int32> ByRef)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities+<>c__DisplayClass1d`1+<<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c>d__1f[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities+<>c__DisplayClass1d`1+<<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c>d__1f[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c>d__1f<Int32> ByRef)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities+<>c__DisplayClass1d`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>b__1c()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`1<System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Int32>>, Boolean)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.RunAsync[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskRunContext, System.Func`1<System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<Int32>>)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities+<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>d__22`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities+<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>d__22`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync>d__22`1<Int32> ByRef)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Roaming.Utilities.ExecuteOnUiThreadAsync[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`1<Int32>)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities+<ResolveFWLinkThroughVsWebProxy>d__5.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities+<ResolveFWLinkThroughVsWebProxy>d__5, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<ResolveFWLinkThroughVsWebProxy>d__5 ByRef)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkThroughVsWebProxy(System.Uri, Boolean, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Logger)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities+<ResolveFWLinkAsync>d__f.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities+<ResolveFWLinkAsync>d__f, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<ResolveFWLinkAsync>d__f ByRef)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Utilities.ResolveFWLinkAsync(System.Uri, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Logger, Int32)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserContext+<PrepareToConnectAndComputeCodeMarker>d__20.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserContext+<PrepareToConnectAndComputeCodeMarker>d__20, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<PrepareToConnectAndComputeCodeMarker>d__20 ByRef)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserContext.PrepareToConnectAndComputeCodeMarker()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession+<ConnectAsyncImpl>d__17.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession+<ConnectAsyncImpl>d__17, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<ConnectAsyncImpl>d__17 ByRef)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsyncImpl(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession+<ConnectAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession+<ConnectAsync>d__2, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<ConnectAsync>d__2 ByRef)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.ConnectAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession+<PollConnectAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession+<PollConnectAsync>d__22, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<PollConnectAsync>d__22 ByRef)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.BaseUserSession.PollConnectAsync()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Poller+<PollAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Poller+<PollAsync>d__3, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]](<PollAsync>d__3 ByRef)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.ConnectedUser.Poller.PollAsync(System.Object)
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallbackInContext(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback()
```