# Unable to open designer for DevExpress version 8.2 in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress, security-policy

I've inherited an old project which uses Devexpress 8.2.4 - so i went and installed an appropriate DXperience Subscription v8.2.4. Now, when I try to open the designer through Visual Studio 2019, I get a:

*"This method explicitly uses CM policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility reasons, please use the NetFx40/LegacySecurtyPolicy configuration switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information."*

Then I tried to open the project in VS 2010, and upon attempt at opening the designer, same CAS policy error happens.
After editing the VS2010 DevEnv configuration file (and respective config file for VS 2019), [as Thomas suggested in his answer **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637089/netfx40-legacysecuritypolicy-in-design-time-mode/65423699#65423699), my Visual Studio 2019 just started crashing during start, and my Visual Studio 2010 successfully started but it then crashed upon trying to select the designer object.

Yes, I'm trying to get this designer for Devexpress 8.2 to run in either IDE - I just need to get it to work so I can hopefully add a QR Code(is this even possible in v8.2.4???).
I just don't know how to access designer to actually graphically update the report. I did some Devexpress projects myself but using v19 and newer, but I'm having trouble now, opening this designer for old Devexpress 8.21.

Any help would be appreciated as this HAS to be done by tomorrow.

Also, if v8.2.4 doesn't support QR Code (an XRBarCode object), what would be an alternative for adding that QR Code functionality? Would I have to upgrade to newer versions - would that break something?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't remember when devexpress had the ability to do QRCodes, but I believe it was after 8.21. We are using 19.1.7 and it works perfectly. I would try and run the 'Project Converter' included in the Devexpress extension toolbar. One thing that I would mention is to look at the references in the solution and make sure that it is not referencing the old version after you convert. This will break the project. I manually had to go through the references and delete the obsolete version.

Comment: Also they made a switch after v16.5 in how the XtraReports are binded to different queries so you will get annoying messages saying would you like to switch to the newer method. which has the ability to break some of your existing reports.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Sadly, I've inherited a mammoth of a project and I'm afraid poking around it might cause domino effect :)
I will try to convert it locally, and if that fails - I'll try editing it in VS 2008 (I asked on their support page and they said v8.2 doesn't support 2010 or later versions). And if there isn't a QR Code in v8.2, perhaps I'll try a workaround by inserting QR Code generated elsewhere, as a picture perhaps(if they support inserting pictures, I'm not even sure)?

Comment: I hear ya! when we have to convert our project to a newer version we usually spend about a day or two fixing some stuff they consider obsolete. I would also tell ya if you do convert it locally and it goes through make sure when you are publishing the project to delete the bin folder and have it recreated. We have an issue with that every so often.

Comment: If you have access to dev azure you could always create a new local branch and do some testing on that. That project convert will only access your active branch. So if it does mess anything up you can always go back to your previous working project. Also I believe they supported inserting pictures on that version but I am not positive